# What is debconf -communicate?

Tags: debian, ubuntu

On my freshly installed ubuntu 18.04, after updating , a window has come up named "debconf-communicate".It says 'configuring console setup' and asking me to select encoding (UTF8,ISO 8859 etc ). I do not know what should I select .

Comment: add the debian tag

Answer (score 2):

That is `debconf`, a part of the package management system, asking a question in order to finalize the configuration of a particular package.

In this case, the package is probably `console-setup`, which is responsible for the selection of keyboard, font and character settings on the text console. It won't affect the character set choices in the GUI environment... although it's probably a good idea to set the text console to use the same character set as the GUI, in case some other problem forces you to use the text console to fix things.

In general, UTF8 is probably the best "universal" choice, as it allows full Unicode support but is still fully compatible with basic ASCII.

I'd recommend picking UTF8 unless you specifically know otherwise, for example if you're installing the system for the specific purpose of processing text-based data that uses a non-UTF8 encoding, or are located somewhere with strong localization preferences for a particular character encoding over UTF8.

Comment: Good answer. For instance here you only use other encoding when migrating legacy apps, and again, if there is no alternative. +1